# Tomcat6 -> how to put a project into the root folder?

Tags: linux, tomcat, tomcat6, fedora

I have a Tomcat6 server on a Linux server. The structure of the `webapps` directory is:

- examples
- host-manager
- manager
- ROOT
- sample

I have a web application running on my localhost on a Tomcat. I created a war file `MyProject.war` and put it into the webapps directory. Restarting the Tomcat server, the war is extracted and I have this structure:

- examples
- host-manager
- manager
- **MyProject**
- ROOT
- sample

Calling the URL `http://mysubdomain.mysite.com:8080/` I get the Tomcat start page with

> If you're seeing this page with a web browser, it means you've setup Tomcat successfully. Congratulations!.

Calling `http://mysubdomain.mysite.com:8080/MyProject/` I get the page of my project.

What I want, is that I can access my project with the URL `http://mysubdomain.mysite.com:8080/` and not with `http://mysubdomain.mysite.com:8080/MyProject/`

How can I do this?

Best Regards.

**Update**
I have this in my server.xml:

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
    <Context docBase="MyProject" path="/" />
</Host>
```

I did it on path with an empty string and / and restart Tomcat. Both does not work. The main directory shows me the Tomcat start page instead of my project. The project is only reachable with ...:8080/MyProject/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delete `ROOT` folder, rename `MyProject.war` to `ROOT.war` and restart.

You can also do it by adding the following line to inside the `<Host>` entry of `/conf/server.xml`

```
<Context docBase="MyProject" path="" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Where can I write/change the `docBase` attribute of the Context element on my server?

Comment: Click the link behind `<Context>` in my answer for possible locations. I personally suggest `/META-INF/context.xml` file inside the webapp in question.

Comment: I searched, but inside my project, there is no `context.xml`. In `META-INF` there is only a `MANIFEST.MF`

Comment: Sorry, I have to take it back. For a webapp which is to be deployed as ROOT, you can't declare it like that in `context.xml` (otherwise, you just create one yourself).

Comment: I add the line with `Context` to the `server.xml` and restart the Tomcat server (I updated my question). So this solution does not work or I did something wrong?

Comment: I have the solution. I have to write an ending slash to the `docBase`. So it must be `<Context docBase="MyProject/" path="" />`.

Comment: @Tim: try with `path=""` should also work, not `path="/"` and no trailing slash on the MyProject

Comment: Hm, it only works with the ending slash on MyProject in my case. But it works, so everything is okay for me.